# TFS2018 : Parallel builds executed after pause and Resume

Tags: tfs, resume, pause

We see that when we pause any build definition in TFS2018 and resume, Builds waiting in the queue are all running in parallel.

While this looks good to have multiple builds running parallel, it creates some problems particularly on gated definitions :

- creating merge conflicts
- Availability of agents for other builds

I could not find much info on internet except one on [VS developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/154587/on-resume-paused-build-will-run-all-triggered-buil.html) if there is any solution or fix in future TFS update versions

Can someone provide some additional information on this behavior

Environment : TFS 2018 U2 Release environment

TFS Agent version : 2.122.1

Comment: This behavior is observed even in the new version of TFS 2018 Update3 . Not sure if this is a feature itself

Comment: Would you prefer them to just run serial?  Or would you prefer that they just not be queued?